# Three.js use VideoTexture on Android Wechat

Tags: android, three.js, webgl, wechat

VideoTexture is not available on Android WeChat, the video can be played, but the material is still black, I tried the Android native browser and it is normal.
How to solve this problem, or what alternatives, I want to render a video to my material. I tried to use gif, but currently he only updates on Edge.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_video.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add specific attribute to your video tag for videos to work in Android Wechat Browser like this:

```
<video 
   src="xxx" 
   x5-video-player-type="h5"
/>
```

You could refer to this: https://x5.tencent.com/tbs/guide/video.html